# How do I wrap a Knockout Tree inside a Knockout DropDownButton?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having trouble with jqWidgets KnockoutJS UI controls. My goal is to be able to create a knockout dropdown tree. They have an example of in jQueryUI form [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/index.htm#demos/jqxtree/dropdowntree.htm), but not in KnockoutJS. The problem I believe is due to the order of operations of rendering. Naturally I've tried to numerous ways of achieving this such as

```
<div data-bind="jqxDropDownButton:{}"><div data-bind="jqxTree:{}"></div</div>
```

The problem with the above code is that the jqxDropDownButton renders html overriding the inner jqxTree html which then never achieves to render at all. I've also tried programmatically with ko.bindingHandlers.customDropDownTree. In this instance I've tried rendering each control into a html variable and then wrapping the jqxDropDownButton html around the jqxTree. This somewhat works but it places the wrapping in the wrong place. Can someone please help???

```
<div data-bind="customDropDownTree:{}"></div>
ko.bindingHandlers.customDropDownTree = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
    var $el = $(element),
        $btn = $('<div />'),
        options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        src = {
            datatype: 'json',
            datafields: [{
                name: 'id'
            }, {
                name: 'parentID'
            }, {
                name: 'label'
            }, {
                name: 'value'
            }, {
                name: 'html'
            }, {
                name: 'disabled'
            }, {
                name: 'checked'
            }, {
                name: 'expanded'
            }, {
                name: 'selected'
            }, {
                name: 'items'
            }, {
                name: 'icon'
            }, {
                name: 'iconsize'
            }],
            id: 'id',
            localdata: options.source
        },
        dp = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(src, {
            loadComplete: function (records) {
                $el.jqxTree({
                    source: dp.records
                });
            }
        });
    dp.dataBind();

    $btn.jqxDropDownButton();
    $el.jqxTree();

    $btn.on('open', function () {
        if ($el.jqxDropDownButton('isOpened')) {}
    });



    $el.on('select', function (event) {
        var args = event.args,
            item = $el.jqxTree('getItem', args.element),
            ddContent = '<div style="position: relative; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 5px;">' + item.label + '</div>';
    });

    $btn.jqxDropDownButton('setContent', '<div style="position: relative; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 5px;">Select Category</div>');

    $el.wrap($btn.html());
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback($el, function () {
        $el.jqxTree("destroy");
    });
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback($btn, function () {
        $btn.jqxDropDownButton('destroy');
    });
}};
```

Comment: They do have examples on Knockout integration: to get you started, here's a link: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxknockout/index.htm?(ui-darkness)#demos/jqxknockout/tree.htm

Comment: It's not the knockout integration that I'm having a problem with... it's the combining/wrapping of two knockout type of controls together.

Comment: I would like to add this forum to this question post as well. http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/knockout-tree-dropdownbutton/#post-77073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the tools you're using, but it looks like you have available to you custom binding handlers for the `jqxDropDownButton` and `jqxTree`, and the only problem is that you can't use them both together.

Have a look at the "wrapper" sections of [this document](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html). You should be able to call your custom binding handlers' `init` and `update` routines from within a new custom binding handler. Since `jqxDropDownButton` apparently writes HTML on its `init`, you'd want to apply that first, then `jqxTree` on an element inside it. That should put it together the way you want.